# Django template displaying images in wrong position

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-template-filters

I'm new to Django so apologies if this one is silly. I have a Django template with three spots for images, and I'm trying to let an admin user choose which image in the database should go in which spot (left, middle or right). However,

My model looks like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.text import slugify

class Artwork(models.Model):

    art = models.ImageField(upload_to='artworks/%Y')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    herochoices = [('left', 'left'), ('middle', 'middle'), ('right', 'right')]
    hero = models.CharField(choices=herochoices, max_length=6, unique=True, null=True, blank=True, error_messages={'unique':'Another artwork already uses this hero position.'})  
    slug = slugify(title, allow_unicode=False)

    def get_absolute_urls(self):
        return reverse('artwork_list', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

And my template looks like this:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        {% for artwork in object_list %}
            {% if artwork.hero == 'left' %}
                <div class="col-sm p-3 align-items-center">
                    <img class="img-fluid rounded" src="{{ artwork.art.url }}" />
                    <p>{{ artwork.hero }}</p> <!--for testing-->
                </div>
            {% elif artwork.hero == 'middle' %}
                <div class="col-sm p-3 align-items-center">
                    <img class="img-fluid rounded" src="{{ artwork.art.url }}" />
                    <p>{{ artwork.hero }}</p> <!--for testing-->
                </div>
            {% elif artwork.hero == 'right' %}
                <div class="col-sm p-3 align-items-center">
                    <img class="img-fluid rounded" src="{{ artwork.art.url }}" />
                    <p>{{ artwork.hero }}</p> <!--for testing-->
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

For some reason the images are displayed in the wrong order:

[image]

I have been looking at this for forever, any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Hint, they are shown in exact order you pull them from database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template you are generating with Django is not the following, since the for loop does simply follow the queryset items order.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm p-3 align-items-center">
      <img class="img-fluid rounded" src="{{ LEFT URL }}" />
      <p>{{ LEFT HERO }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm p-3 align-items-center">
      <img class="img-fluid rounded" src="{{ MIDDLE URL }}" />
      <p>{{ MIDDLE HERO }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm p-3 align-items-center">
      <img class="img-fluid rounded" src="{{ RIGHT URL }}" />
      <p>{{ RIGHT URL }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this snippet, three images will be ordered. If you have more than three, you should make the queryset "smarter" (i.e. a simple get won't work).

**URL**:

```py
def example(request):
    qs = Artwork.objects.all()
    objects_list = [qs.get(hero=position) for position in ["left", "middle", "right"]]
    return render("test.html", { "objects_list": objects_list})
```

**HTML**:

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    {% for artwork in object_list %}
    <div class="col-sm p-3 align-items-center">
      <img class="img-fluid rounded" src="{{ artwork.art.url }}" />
      <p>{{ artwork.hero }}</p>
      <!--for testing-->
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Thank you for that, I'll give it a try. Gotta admit I did not even know about querysets, so thank you for that tip as well!

Comment: Thank you ionpoint, that really helped! I implemented your solution slightly differently (using Q in a filter queryset added to the view):

`queryset = Artwork.objects.filter(Q(hero='left') | Q(hero='middle') | Q(hero='right')).order_by('hero') #order the hero images on the home page`

Anyway it works perfectly now, thank you so much!